# SQL rollup - prevent summing records multiple times

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Firstly, I could not think of a better question title. Apologies for that.

So, I am writing a query and here is something(I think) it would return without aggregating functions and group by. I am using this as an example and actual query contains a lot more fields:

```
SUBJ   CLASSROOM   CLASSROOM_CAPACITY
A      1           25
B      2           50
C      3           60
A      2           50
A      1           25 <--Not actually duplicate
```

Now you would say there are duplicate records. But in fact they are not duplicate in a way that there are some extra fields(not shown here) which would have different values for those seemingly duplicate records.

What I want:

```
SUBJ  CLASSROOM  CLASSROOM_CAPACITY
A     1          25
      2          50
      TOTAL      75
B     2          50
      TOTAL      50
C     3          60
      TOTAL      60
//EDIT - Apparently following line is causing too much confusion. Ignore it. How can I get rest of the table correctly?
TOTAL            135 //It seems its quite difficult to get 135 here. Its ok if this total is messed up
```

What I am trying:

```
SELECT
SOME_FIELDS,
SUBJ,
CLASSROOM,
SUM(CLASSROOM_CAPACITY)
FROM
MYTABLE
WHERE .....
GROUP BY SOME_FIELDS, ROLLUP(SUBJ,CLASSROOM)
```

The problem:
Thanks to those "seemingly duplicate" records, classroom capacities are being summed up multiple times. How do I prevent that? Am I doing this the wrong way?
The actual query is lot more complicated but I think if I can get this right, I can apply it to bigger query.

PS: I know how to get text "Total" instead of blank entry with `ROLLUP` using `GROUPING` so you can skip that part.

Comment: How do you get a grand total of 135?  What values are you summing and what values are you excluding to get that?  How do you know which values to include?

Comment: I am not getting it. I want to get it. Its sum of classroom capacities of all classrooms for the listed subjects 25+50+60. But that's not important. I want at least other totals to be right

Comment: I know it's a bad example. But it's the best I could come up with..

Comment: Why are you excluding `A,2,50` from the total, but including it in the subtotal for `A`? I'm struggling to understand your logic. How do *you* get 135 - not what you think the SQL should be, you need to be able to explain it in words first (a specification, if you will).

Comment: @AlexPoole: Apologies for confusion. So imagine that I am running a school that teaches subjects A,B,C and my school building has 3 classrooms. There are multiple classes for each of these subjects  scheduled among the three classrooms. What 135 indicates is grand total of classroom capacity when I count each classroom only once. Or you can say its occupancy of my building. However, you can ignore the 135 grand total record for the time. How can I get rest of the table right? Like up to `TOTAL 60`

Answer (score 1):

The cardinality you're introducing is a little off and when you sort the that ROLLUP starts to work. Your saying that:

```
SUBJ  CLASSROOM  CLASSROOM_CAPACITY
A     1          25
```

is equal to:

```
SUBJ  CLASSROOM  CLASSROOM_CAPACITY
A     1          25
```

But the `SOME_FIELDS` could vary per row. When you aggregate up to just the columns above, what do you expect to happen to `SOME_FIELDS`?

If these can be ignore for the purposes of this query your best bet is to first find the `DISTINCT` records (i.e. records that contain a unique tuple of subj, classroom and classroom_capacity) and then do the ROLLUP on this data set. The following query achieves this:

```
WITH distinct_subj_classrm_capacity AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    subj
  , classroom
  , classroom_capacity
  FROM mytable
)
SELECT
  subj
, classroom
, SUM(classroom_capacity)
FROM distinct_subj_classrm_capacity
GROUP BY ROLLUP(subj, classroom)
```

If you're not interested in the break report results that ROLLUP gives you and you simply want the raw totals then you can use the analytic version of SUM (see here for more on Oracle analytic functions: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm)

```
WITH distinct_subj_classrm_capacity AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    subj
  , classroom
  , classroom_capacity
  FROM mytable
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  subj
, SUM(classroom_capacity) OVER (PARTITION BY subj) classroom_capacity_per_subj
FROM distinct_subj_classrm_capacity
```

This gives results in the format:

```
SUBJ  CLASSROOM_CAPACITY_PER_SUBJ
A     75
B     50
C     60
```

Comment: Thanks. `SOME_FIELDS` add up in rollup because they are wrapped in `SUM()`. I'll experiment with distinct.